# Haskell Where Syntax

Tags: haskell, syntax, where-clause

wondering what's syntactically wrong with this function?

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime a = go a (a - 1)
        where 
        go a b 
        |b == 1 = True
        |a / b == 0 = False
        |otherwise = isPrime a (b - 1)
```

Just a simple function to determine whether a number is prime or not, thanks.

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime a = go a (a - 1)
    where 
        go a b 
            |b == 1 = True
            |a / b == 0 = False
            |otherwise = isPrime a (b - 1)
```

I now have this, but still get compilation errors?

Comment: You need to indent the guards for `go` so that they're passed the declaration of `go`.  If you're using tabs to indent, stop, this is a problem I see on SO very frequently.  Just change your editor settings to insert spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: The reason I say use spaces over tabs is because your editor and GHC will see the spaces as the same number of columns, but that's not necessarily true for tabs.  GHC views tabs as a fixed column width (I believe 8), but most people have their editor configured for 4 columns.  Also should have mentioned that the declaration for `go` needs to start after the `where`, so switch to spaces, put 4 in front of `where`, 8 in front of `go a b` and 12 in front of each guard.

Comment: Thanks, made the changes you suggested, but still getting compilation issues?

Comment: Is it about your use of `/`?  That would be a type error because you can't divide integers.  The `/` operator only works on numbers that are fractional.  Instead you can use the ````div```` function as a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Yes that was a part of the issue, thanks, also fixed the logic in the function :P

Comment: @bheklilr `go` doesn't actually need to be indented more than `where`, the latter isn't really indentation sensitive. I used to put `where`s at the end of long lines far to the right of the block  and it worked fine, although I seem to have discarded that habit lately for ordinary `where` blocks. Still do it in class/instance declarations and the like.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen The expressions in a `where` block have to be indented further than the line the `where` is on.  If you have `foo x = y + x * y where\n\ty = x * x`, then `y` is still indented further than the line that `where` appears. (`\n\t` used here because comments don't support multi-line code snippets, replace with a newline and 4 spaces please)

Comment: @bheklilr No, it has to be indented further than the *block statement* the `where` is in. The `where` doesn't have be on the first line of that statement, in which case its own line can be indented more. E.g. the following is perfectly legal if perhaps bad style: `foo x = y + x * y\n\t\twhere\n\ty = x * x`

Comment: @bheklilr A more realistic example that I would actually have written at one time is if the expression after `foo x` were split on multiple lines, I might have put the `where` at the end of its last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Haskell programs have to be well indented! That is how to indent your program well:

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime a = go a (a - 1)
  where -- indent before `where` 
    go a b -- indent after `where`'s indent
      | b == 1     = True
      | a / b == 0 = False
      | otherwise  = isPrime a (b - 1)
```

If you'll edit your code in this way, you'll still get error when compile it. The reason is because you are trying to call `isPrime` with two arguments in `go`'s body, but it takes only one (that is stated in `isPrime`'s annotation). To edit it, you just need to replace `isPrime a (b - 1)` to `go a (b - 1)`.

After that edit, you'll get another error when compile the program: `a` stated to be `Int`, but you are applying fractional division to it with `/` operator. For `Int` type only integer division is allowed:

```
a `div` b == 0 = False
```

But you don't need to apply that division at all. To state whether the one number can be divided by another you should take a rest of division and compare it with zero:

```
a `mod` b == 0 = False
```

So, final program will be:

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime a = go a (a - 1)
  where -- indent before `where` 
    go a b -- indent after `where`'s indent
      | b == 1         = True
      | a `mod` b == 0 = False
      | otherwise      = go a (b - 1)
```